# Is there a way to tell if SharePoint was installed using a SQL Alias?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sql-server, upgrade, sql, upgrade-sharepoint

I know that a SQL Alias is listed now but I would like to find out if SharePoint was installed while specifying that alias during the install.  On the 'Servers in Farm' page, I see both a SQL Alias and the SQL Instance listed, so I am a bit suspicious.  How can I determine for certain how SharePoint was initially installed, via the SQL Alias or via the SQL Instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, check the configuration database server name. Because Config db is the 1st database which is configured during the SharePoint deployment, DB server name will tell you If that is using the SQL Alias or SQL instance name?

i usually use the following script to get the config db server name:

```
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.Type -eq "Configuration Database"}).server
```

here is the link for it.

https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/29/get-sharepoint-config-database-server-via-powershell/